# get package installer

Tags: android, google-play, android-package-managers

I'd like to add an unlocker for my app, which is only available on the Play Store. How can I check, if the package was installed by the Play Store? I've seen this in SD Maid, but I didn't find a solution yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a method for that:
[PackageManager.getInstallerPackageName(String packageName)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager#getInstallerPackageName(java.lang.String));
This returns the package name of the installer application.

Answer (score 0):

```
val Context.installerPackageName
    get() = try {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.R)
            packageManager.getInstallSourceInfo(packageName).installingPackageName
        else {
            @Suppress("DEPRECATION")
            packageManager.getInstallerPackageName(packageName)
        }
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        null
    }
```